# How to take the meaning of "gang lines"?

Tags: meaning

> [A bad batch of drugs flattens users across the city and causes a ripple effect that extends far beyond familiar gang lines.](https://www.theguardian.com/tv-and-radio/2023/mar/27/blue-lights-review-dont-sleep-on-this-fantastically-tense-belfast-cop-show)

What does "gang lines" mean in this context?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should understand this as the lines of division in society between different gangs.

So the consequences of this batch of drugs does not just affect one gang, but multiple gangs (across gang lines) and users who are not part of those gangs (beyond gang lines).

Answer (score 0):

A gang is an organised group of criminals.
A line is -- well, you know what a line is. You can draw it on a map.

Each gang operates in a certain area. If a gang member wanders into the wrong area, maybe he will be shot or stabbed.

The (invisible) divisions on the map between different gangs' territories are the "lines".

I think James K is right in saying that "beyond gang lines" doesn't just mean "further away than the territory boundaries where gangs are fighting", but rather figuratively "having more impact than just the gang members on the streets".